# Preview Mouse Down event returns sender with null referenced CurrentColumn when called first time

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, currentitem

I run my application and fill datagrid with data. Then I click on some row and handle event in following way:

```
  private void dataGridCanTabParamList_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var buffer = sender as DataGrid;

        if ((buffer == null) || (buffer.CurrentColumn == null) )
            return;

        SetCanPropertyDesription(buffer.CurrentColumn.Header.ToString());

    }
```

When I run this event first time the CurrentColumn is null, when I run this event second time clicking in exactly the same position CurrentColumn contains data. CurrentItem is also empty when clicked first time.

Why I don't see the data at first click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because CurrentColumn and CurrentItem refer to selected Column/Item. When you first click, nothing is selected as you handle the tunneled event (so your code is executed before the DataGrid actually set the current item) . When you click for the second time, CurrentColumn and CurrentItem have already been set.

Comment: Is there other good event to use to access of current used column? Earlier I was using onSelectionChanged - but... it apears only on selection changed.

Comment: You can use the Bubbled event : MouseDown. But I'm almost certain this event will be already handled, so you will have to attach your handler in code behind using `UIElement.AddHandler` Method, specifying you want to handle events that are already handled. There may be a most suitable event though.

Answer (score 4):

`PreviewMouseDownEvent` is tunneling event which is raised before actual `MouseDown` event.

And `MouseDown event(handled by DataGridCell)` is responsible for the selection of column in dataGrid. So, at first time your no cell is selected hence `CurrentItem` and `CurrentColumn` is null at that time.

See the propagation of events that how it works -

[image]